# How to parse this JSON string properly

Tags: vb.net

I have some API That returns the following JASON, and im trying to parse it to be able to pull from any attributes i want.

JSON im trying to parse: https://pastebin.com/i06GRD0f

I'm assuming the proper way would be to load everything into an array but i can't get it to work right as it's a little confusing with all different parameters.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization


Public Class ServerAttributes
    Public Property assists() As String
    Public Property bestRankPoint() As String
    Public Property boosts() As String
    Public Property dBNOs() As String
    Public Property dailyKills() As String
    Public Property dailyWins() As String

    Public Property damageDealt() As String
    Public Property days() As String
    Public Property headshotKills() As String
    Public Property heals() As String
    Public Property killPoints() As String
    Public Property kills() As String

    Public Property longestKill() As String
    Public Property longestTimeSurvived() As String
    Public Property losses() As String
    Public Property maxKillStreaks() As String
    Public Property mostSurvivalTime() As String
    Public Property rankPoints() As String

    Public Property rankPointsTitle() As String
    Public Property revives() As String
    Public Property rideDistance() As String
    Public Property roadKills() As String
    Public Property roundMostKills() As String
    Public Property roundsPlayed() As String

    Public Property suicides() As String
    Public Property swimDistance() As String
    Public Property teamKills() As String
    Public Property timeSurvived() As String
    Public Property top10s() As String
    Public Property vehicleDestroys() As String

    Public Property walkDistance() As String
    Public Property weaponsAcquired() As String
    Public Property weeklyKills() As String
    Public Property weeklyWins() As String
    Public Property winPoints() As String
    Public Property wins() As String
End Class

Public Class ServerData
    Public Property data() As ServerAttributes
End Class

Module StaterMainClass
    Public Sub GetInfo()
        Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim DataResponse As ServerData = jss.Deserialize(Of ServerData)(JSON)

        Debug.Print(DataResponse.data.assists(0))
   End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Look into [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: The deserializer has no idea of what you want it to return using just a section of the content without any other reference. That JSON `RootObject` contains 3 sub-objects: `{ data, links, meta}`. The `data` member contains a string and 2 objects: `{ type (string), attributes, relationships }`. You're after the `attributes` content. `attributes` contains 1 object `{ gameModeStats }` which contains 6 object of the type you're showing here. You need to speficy from where you want to extract your data (Mind, you have 6 objects of the same type).

Comment: Hey Jimi, you're correct. I'd like to be able to pull a value from any of the attributes under any of the 6 different objects. Here's an example: [link](https://i.imgur.com/4Du968W.png) Im just not sure how to load each of the 6 objects and reference them properly to be able to pull attributes from any of the 6 objects i require.

Comment: so i came up with this: [link](https://pastebin.com/N2S05mZF)

One thing im unsure of is, im parsing objects with "-" in the name spacing(ex: duo-fpp), how do avoid VB causing an error with "-"?

Comment: First thing: do you need the entire JSON or just the `duo`, `duo-fpp` etc. parts? If you need to whole JSON converted to classes, you class structure is almost ready. Mind that you need just one class object for all the `duo`, `duo-fpp` etc. objects, because they're identical in content (same properties). You can use a `JsonProperty` attribute to convert the properties names. E.g.,  `<JsonProperty("squad-fpp")> Public Property SquadFpp As [Some class]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far Jimi, im actually getting somewhere.

This is what i have so far: [link](https://pastebin.com/Xrp49f9V)

When i run the code, i get a system.nullreferenceexception. Im assuming it's still not parsing the data correctly with the above code. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: `<JsonProperty>` is used with `JSon.Net`. JavaScriptSeriaizer doesn't have that decoration. Possibly, use `JSon.Net` instead. You can install it as a NuGet package from your Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager. It's much more flexible.

Comment: I used the Package manager to install Newtonsoft.Json, the decoration works with that package. Im getting the error on the "  Debug.Print(DataResponse.data.attributes.gameModeStats.SquadFpp.heals) " Line is returning null still ;/

Details: 
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

PubgStater.GameModeStats.SquadFpp.get returned Nothing."

Comment: After some testing, it seems that it might be that decoration isn't working. If i pull from the other values such as "squad" and not one that uses the JsonProperty, it works! We're getting somewhere now ;)

Comment: `<JsonProperty>` works just fine. But, it must match the JSON property name exactly. Not a strict requirement, anyway, you should have the decoration and the Property declarations in two lines. Also, see that you're actually using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` and not the JavaScriptSerializer one :)

Comment: LOL! Jimi, you're a beast!

Dim DataResponse As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(responseReader.ReadToEnd())

Solved my issues. I was using the javascriptserializer(), good catch there! Thank you so much for your help, everything is working like a charm now!

Comment: Well, good job then :)